# Return data from a pending promise

Tags: javascript, node.js, es6-promise

Trying to store the response into a variable. Not sure what I'm doing wrong. Any help would be appreciated.

```js
async function fetchData(url) {
  const response = await fetch(url);

  if (!response.ok) {
    const message = `An error has occured: ${response.status}`;
    throw new Error(message);
  }

  const data = await response.json();
  return data;
}

async function getActivities() {
  let response = null;
  try {
    response = await fetchData("https://www.boredapi.com/api/activity");
    return response;
  } catch (error) {
    throw error;
  }
}

let data = getActivities();
console.log(data);
```

Comment: You have to await for the getActivities() to be fulfilled. Try this `let data = await getActivities();`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will have to wait for the promise returned from `getActivities` to resolve. Since you marked that funcition as `async`, it will return a promise that resolves to the function's return value.

For example:

```js
getActivities()
    .then(data => console.log(data));
```

---

Alternatively, wrap your application logic into an `async` function, which would allow you to use `await`:

```js
async function main() {
  let data = await getActivities();
  console.log(data);
}
main();
```

Once [top level awaits](https://github.com/tc39/proposal-top-level-await) are a thing, wrapping your logic in a main function will be unnecessary.

Comment: Thanks for looking into this problem. Actually, I'm looking for a slightly different solution here. Like I showed in my code example, I'm trying to return data from the promise and store it inside a variable. With your example, I'm unable to do it.

let data = null
getActivities().then((response) => {
  data = response.type
});

console.log(data)

Comment: @AnonymousAnonymous The issue is that the statements after `getActivities` continue to be executed while the promise is still being resolved. For this reason, this won't work as expected. Two options: either put all logic that depends on the result of the promise into the `then` block, or move your logic into a `main` function or so, so you're able to use `await getActivities()`. I'll add an example for the second approach to my answer.

Comment: Top level awaits are currently in a proposal stage, and would help with this: https://github.com/tc39/proposal-top-level-await

Answer (score 0):

Using the same logic you used inside your functions,
`console.log()` would execute well before your data is returned.

You can use a `.then()`

```
getActivities().then(data => 
{ console.log(data);
});
```

Or if you want to go with another `async/await`

```
(async randomFunction() {
let data = await getActivities();
console.log(data);
}());
```